# How to get firebase data for the development of the project?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have built this website using reactjs, firebase. I would like to know if someone wants to contribute to this project how should he/she get the data that is stored in my firebase account for the development of the website? https://www.codingspace.codes/

I know they need to create a new firebase project but how do they get the exact data that is on my website.
I don’t have any idea, anyone please help me with this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very open-ended question, typically though if it's for local development I'd just give them access to the firebase project as a collaborating member.

Alternatively, you could be looking into the import/export features of Firebase.

Use the firestore export command to export all the documents in your database, replacing `[BUCKET_NAME]` with the name of your Cloud Storage bucket. Add the --async flag to prevent the gcloud tool from waiting for the operation to complete.

```
gcloud firestore export gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

And importing it on their project in a similar manner:

Use the firestore import command to import documents from a previous export operation.

```
gcloud firestore import gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[EXPORT_PREFIX]/
```

where `[BUCKET_NAME]` and `[EXPORT_PREFIX]` point to the location of your export files.

See the documentation for further details https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import

Comment: "if it's for local development I'd just give them access to the firebase project as a collaborating member." I would like to know more about this. Let say someone creates a new document from the local development to the firebase DB then it'll get show on the production as well. How should I deal with this.

Comment: I would create two firebase projects, one for development and one for production. This will allow you to make changes and easily test things out without breaking your app for your users.

Comment: so, I need to copy data from my production to the development firebase project, and do I need to share the firebase project credentials with the collaborators?

Comment: That is one way, you wouldn't share the credentials with someone, but in the Firebase console, you're able to add them as a user which will give them access via their own account. Be careful using production data for development purposes though, make sure you're not exposing customer/sensitive information in the development environment.

Comment: One more thing Is there any better way to move data from my production to development? and In my user's collection, I have data like email, name, uniqueId of the user. Should I share these things in the development?

Comment: and which type of role should I give for the development of the project.
I added a ss

Comment: The question to ask yourself is do other developers need to know customers' usernames and emails in order to do their work? Would it do to just have one customer called "John" with an email of "john@example.com"? As for what role, again it depends on what you want other developers to do. Being able to read the data might be enough, or you might want them to have complete control over the project in which case you'd give them owner rights.

Comment: Okay! makes sense to me :)
I can give them roles according to their role in the project. Let's say someone wants to make UI changes then I can give him/her a read role.
Thanks for very much for your help